# Generar evento al hacer click en un formulario vb.net

Tags: vb.net, click

Tengo una aplicación en vb.net con visual studio 2017 y necesito que al hacer click en cualquier parte del formulario se ejecute un sub con código. He intentado hacerlo así:

```
Public Sub Principal_Click() Handles Me.MouseClick
    minuto = TimeOfDay.Minute
End Sub
```

Para hacerlo me he basado en el evento KeyPress, y pensé que funcionaría pero no ha sido así. Da igual cuantas veces pinche en cualquier parte del formulario, que no me ejecuta ese sub. 
Os agradezco de antemano la ayuda que podáis darme!

Comment: ¿Pero estás haciendo click sobre el fondo del formulario o sobre algún control? Entiendo que estamos hablando de Windows Forms ¿no?

Comment: Si, perdona, hablamos de windows forms. El click quiero que se capture siempre que se haga click sobre el fondo del formulario o sobre cualquier cosa. ¿Sabrías como hacerlo?

Comment: @walkerdeath Puedes capturar el evento click del mouse y detectar si está clicando dentro de la pantalla para ejecutar el código que necesitas.

Comment: Eso es lo que he intentado, pero no he conseguido implementarlo correctamente. Pongo un punto de interrupción en el sub y cuando ejecuto la aplicación nunca entra. Evidentemente algo estoy haciendo mal, pero no tengo ni idea de qué.... Aun así muchas gracias por el comentario!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos, walkerdeath.

Según entiendo tu pregunta y los comentarios, tu respuesta debería estar aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37639493/8954823

Básicamente es recorrer todos los `controles` del `formulario` en el evento `Load` y direccionar el evento `MouseClick` de cada uno de esos controles hacia el evento `MouseClick` del `formulario`.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each control As Control In Controls
            AddHandler control.MouseClick, AddressOf Form1_Click
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click
        ' Aquí ejecutas el código
        Console.WriteLine("¡Hola, Stack Overflow!") ' código de ejemplo
    End Sub

End Class
```

e.g.: (Presta atención a la consola de salida)

[image: gif]

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    For Each CTRL1 As Control In Me.Controls
        AddHandler CTRL1.MouseClick, AddressOf Form_BringToFront

        For Each CTRL2 As Control In CTRL1.Controls
            AddHandler CTRL2.MouseClick, AddressOf Form_BringToFront

            For Each CTRL3 As Control In CTRL2.Controls
                AddHandler CTRL3.MouseClick, AddressOf Form_BringToFront
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Form_BringToFront()
    Me.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Cómo responde este código a la pregunta? Lee [answer].